# Tabular environment display very weird

Tags: tables

So, to draw a table, I use the following Latex Code:

```
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
$p$ & $\bar{p}$\\
\hline\\
1 & 0\\
0 & 1
\end{tabular}
```

But somehow, this is the outcome

[image]

Can someone please explain where did I made a mistake? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Leave  out the \\ after `\hline`

Comment: You're welcome! I think you could delete your question.

Comment: There are two other "mistakes" in case of a formal table for a serious journal: (1) Vertical lines. Avoid it!  (2) `\hline`. Use  `\toprule`,`\bottomrule` and `\midrule` instead of  `\hline` for horizontal rules (need the the package `booktabs` in the preamble).

Answer (score 4):

Putting a `\\` after the `\hline` is like you are writing a row with empty cells.

The vertical line at the end of the empty row would appear if you wrote `& \\`, but of course you do not want an empty row, so simply leave out the `\\`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
Your table:
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
$p$ & $\bar{p}$\\
\hline\\
1 & 0\\
0 & 1
\end{tabular}

A table with an empty row:
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
$p$ & $\bar{p}$\\
\hline
&\\
1 & 0\\
0 & 1
\end{tabular}

The correct table:
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
$p$ & $\bar{p}$\\
\hline
1 & 0\\
0 & 1
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]